# My custom link works only on home page

Tags: links

I created a custom ID for the Portfolio section on my home page. Then I linked it to the "Portfolio" menu, but for some reason it only works from Home page and not from other pages. I tried to add /home as a part of the link (as were recommended previously for other people having similar issue but) it didn't work.

I would appreciate any help :) Cheers!

[image]

Comment: You've got `//` in front of the URL. Those shouldn't be there.

Comment: Can you please share the url ?

Comment: @TejasGajjar ... It's in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You link to the anchor, so you have to put all link in there. And you've done it.

But there are some additional `"//"` in your URL, so it's not valid URL, so browsers may ignore some part of it.

Just remove those `"//"` and it should work just fine.

Comment: Oh my, how come I didn't notice it before! Thank you so very much, I removed it and it is working!!!